# Ember adapter unbiddenly changing model name from plural to singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have the following Ember adapter for a model called `time-zone`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v2',
  pathForType: function(type) {
    // type here is "time-zone"
    return Ember.String.underscore(type);
  }
});
```

What I want is for my HTTP request to be sent to `/api/v2/time_zones`, but it's coming through as `/api/v2/time_zone`, which is wrong.

This is my model file:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And this is the relevant part of my routing file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      timeZones: this.store.findAll('time-zone')
    });
  }
});
```

Adapting a name like `timeZone` or `time-zone` to an endpoint URI like `/api/v2/time_zones` seems like an *extremely* common use case for Ember, so I'm perplexed at the fact that what I'm trying isn't working.

I can do this and make it work:

```
    return Ember.String.pluralize(Ember.String.underscore(type));
```

But that seems like a silly hack for what again must be a super common use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right when you use pluralize. It says in the [docs](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/pathForType?anchor=pathForType) that by default it will pluralize the type but since you're overriding it you have to pluralize it yourself.